# Android Volley Multiplas Requisições em Paralelo

Tags: android, asynctask, volley

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde tenho que fazer várias requisições volley em paralelo para preencher spinners, e existem dois momentos em que chamo essa tela.

A primeira vez é para um novo cadastro, onde todas as funcionalidades estão de acordo do que eu gostaria.

O segunda vez é para editar o cadastro, onde deveriam carregar os dados dos spinneres e depois preencher com o valor já pre-cadastrado anteriormente pelo usuário. Porém, ao tentar buscar os dados e setar no spinner, os dados ainda não foram trazidos do serviço.

Gostaria de saber qual é a melhor solução para realizar esta tarefa... Ví algumas pessoas falando de AsyncTask, esta seria a melhor opção?

Comment: Coloque o código que está a usar.

Comment: Você quer solucionar a questão de não preenchimento do spinner ou você quer um dica de como e o que usar para consumo de webservice?

Comment: Ambos eu já consegui realizar... apenas queria uma dica em como fazer várias requisições em paralelo e qnd todas estiverem OK, eu chamar o editar

Comment: Eu pessoalmente gosto do `EventBus` https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas de fazer requisições a um Web Services, através de código que talvez tornaria muito extenso ou através de algumas APIs. Por um outro lado, talvez seja um pouco pessoal a escolha de uma ferramenta boa para fazer requisições, por questão também de facilidade, praticidade e questões de documentação. Um fator que deve considerar muito é a performance de sua aplicação, pois o usuário final terá maior satisfação pela fluidez de seu aplicativo.

Se caso você estiver usando JSON, existem alguns *frameworks* que poderá te ajudar bastante. Veja abaixo os exemplos:

- [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)
- [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Outros](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=frameworks%20android%20web%20service%20requirements)

Um [site gringo](http://instructure.github.io/) fez alguns experimentos usando esses mesmos *frameworks*, com uma aplicação bem básica. Os resultados são bem consideráveis pois mostra a eficiência de cada um.

Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para saber mais sobre os testes, leia o artigo [Android Async HTTP Clients: Volley vs Retrofit](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) <sup>(en)</sup>

Acho interessante você ler a documentação de cada um e fazer uma análise de acordo com seus critérios de desenvolvimento, e claro, pensando no usuário final e objetivos do seu projeto. Depois disso, "*taca le pau nesses dedinhos*", *#partiuprogramar #developepment #transformandocaféemcodigos*.

Comment: Então, agradeço muito pela sua resposta que foi bastante completa, mas não é este o tipo de problema que estou enfrentando... O meu problema é que faço as várias requisições com volley, só que precisava que o payload de resposta das requisiçoes estivessem todas prontas para ai então chamar a função de preencher os campos da edição