# Como fazer requisições GET e POST no android, com uma ferramenta rápida e atualizada?

Tags: android, http-request

Eu estou atualmente utilizando o `volley` para requisições web. Mas estou achando essa ferramenta muito lenta.

Pesquisei no google procurando por alternativas, mas todos resultados que encontro são antigos, de 2017, 2016 pra baixo.

Sobre o `org.apache.http` Dizem estar obsoleto, entre outras também obsoletas.

Encontrei pouca informação sobre o `Gson` e pelo que entendi, acho que nem faz requisições web.

Tem gente que fala do `Retrofit` e `Retrofit 2`, que não testei ainda.

Mas afinal, agora no ano de 2018, qual esta sendo o melhor modo de fazer isto? Existe um modo de utilizar as ferramentas nativas do android studio sem instalar nenhuma biblioteca e que não esteja obsoleta?

Desculpem não postar nenhum código, como eu disse não gostei do volley por ser muito lento. Então gostaria mesmo de uma ajuda sobre uma ferramenta mais atualizada. Se possível alguma documentação ou tutorial para utilizar.

Se não fiz a pergunta corretamente por favor me desculpem, eu não sei outro modo de perguntar sobre isto aqui. E pra mim aqui está sendo o único lugar com profissionais que realmente entende do que falam e que poderiam me ajudar.

Estou usando o **android studio 3.1.2**, com `minSdkVersion 15` e `targetSdkVersion 27`

Comment: Utilize https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection, ela é nativa.

Comment: Discordo de algumas coisas. Resultados de 2017, 2016 não são tão antigos assim. Se a Volley está lenta, seria bom examinar em busca da causa da lentidão que pode não ser a volley em si. Quanto à biblioteca nativa, ela é muito baixo nível, sugiro no lugar dela a [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Obrigado, pelo que verifiquei parece que na atualização do android 6.0 eles dizem pra retornar e usar o `HttpURLConnection`. Vou tentar ver como faz o POST e GET com ele. Obrigado.

Comment: @Piovezan Creio que o volley esta muito lento por conta do sistema de cache dele. Para celulares mais velhos e conexão mais lenta ele demora muito pra dar retorno. Mesmo que eu inicie um novo projeto vazio só com ele, a resposta é muita lenta em comparação com outros aplicativos pesados que tenho instalado no meu celular. Sobre o `OkHttp` vou dar uma olhada, mas pq na sua opinião a nativa é muito baixo nível??

Comment: @SamantaSilva Compare uma requisição POST na OkHttp e na HttpURLConnection, a segunda tem bem mais cerimônia, tanto para montar a conexão como para ler os dados recebidos.

Comment: @Piovezan Ahh sim, isso eu imaginava, por ser uma ferramenta nativa deve precisar de muito mais linhas de código. Meu medo é mais por questão de velocidade, performance, e que funcione em todos os dispositivos, desde os mais atuais, ate os mais antigos. Sobre os codigos para o que vou fazer, irei utilizar uma só vez. Então mesmo q seja muito mais trabalhoso não é problema. Desde q funcione bem esta ótimo. Mas eu to gostando tbm do `OkHttp` que você sugeriu. Estou lendo a documentação dele aqui. Obrigadaa.

Comment: @SsmantaSilva Não sei se entendi bem a questão do cache. Se em celulares mais lentos ele atrapalha a performance, talvez fosse o caso de tentar desabilitar o cache. Veja aqui: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333351/disable-volley-cache-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333351/disable-volley-cache-management)

Comment: @SamantaSilva "baixo nível" = mais perto da máquina, menos abstração.

Comment: @Piovezan Ahh eu não sabia que dava pra desabilitar, mas de qualquer modo acho que irei utilizar o `OkHttp` ou `HttpURLConnection`, acho que para meu uso, estes serão bem mais leve pro aplicativo. Mas se caso futuramente eu volte a usar o volley agora eu sei que da pra desabilitar o cache, obrigada mais uma vez pela resposta

Comment: @bfavaretto Obrigada pela explicação

Comment: Uso para projetos empresariais a `Retrofit` há alguns anos, e antes disso usava a `Volley`. Nunca tive problemas com nenhuma das duas, sempre atenderam muito bem.

Comment: @LMaker Mesmo em aparelhos mais antigos e conexões lentas você nunca teve problemas com eles?? Eu estava usando o volley, e uma requisição simples para retornar dados em json de 2 linhas estava demorando mais do que receber fotos no whatsapp, navegar no facebook, ou listar arquivos do google fotos.  Eu acho que o problema da demora do volley era por conta do cache, acima tem um amigo que me ensinou como desabilitar, mas to achando o metodo nativo muito mais rápido agora e estou gostando bastante.

Comment: [Comparação entre todas as Bibliotecas para requisição Http no android! Vá de Retrofit =)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @SamantaSilva nunca tive problemas. Usava um Pixi 3 pra testes na minha antiga empresa e nunca passei por lentidão assim. Certeza que não era problema no backend?

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173757/35406

Comment: @LMaker Acho que não era o backend não, mudei para o `Okhttp` utilizando os mesmos links e a mesma logica de requisição, e a diferença de velocidade foi muito grande. Muito mais rápido do que o volley. Não testei com Retrofit, pq eu li a documentação e vi que o retrofit trabalha com OkHttp, então fiz direto sem precisar passar por essa biblioteca.

Comment: @AllefSousa Obrigada pela indicação, eu ja resolvi com o OkHttp, e foi muito melhor que o volley. Adoreiii.

Comment: @Viana Eu vi o seu link, sobre a comparação entre volley e retrofit eu entendi, mas não entendi o que o AnsyTask está fazendo la. Pq o AnsyTask não tem nada a ver com requisições web, não é mesmo?? pelo que entendo ele serve para execução de uma thread em segundo plano não é isso?? me corrija se eu estiver errada.  Eu utilizei o OkHttp dentro de uma AnsyTask no meu aplicativo e ameiii o resultado e a velocidade.

Answer (score 1):

em build.gradle
adicione

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
depois chame em sua Activity Ion.with(Context).load(url);
```

exemplo

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = "Login";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_identidade_digital);
    EditText   mUsuarioView  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mUsuarioView);
    EditText   mPasswordView  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mPasswordView);
    Login(mUsuarioView.getText().toString(),mPasswordView.getText().toString());
}
public void Login(String user, String senha){

    Ion.with(this).load("https://wwww.meuwebservice.com.br")
            .setBodyParameter("user", user)
            .setBodyParameter("senha", senha)
            .asJsonObject().setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
            if(e != null){
               // algo deu errado
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            } else if (result.get("retorno").getAsString().equals("YES")) {
               //   tudo ceto trabalhe no seu retorno pegando o resultado
                //seu metodo aqui

            }

        }
    });

}
```

[Rede Assíncrona Android e Carregamento de Imagens](https://github.com/koush/ion)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Maycon, você sabe me dizer o que tem nessa biblioteca que você indicou que pode ser melhor que o OkHttp?? Até agora a biblioteca "OkHttp" que foi indicado aqui na resposta, esta parecendo ser o melhor método até agora.